# Summation/counting over overlapping values or dates with group by over id's in sql

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I am working with an sas table and the dates are represented as numbers given in columns "entered" and "left" . I have to count the days the member remained in the system. Like, for example below for id 1, the person entered on 7071 and again used a different product on 7075 although he remained continuously in system from 7071 to 7083. That is the dates overlap. I want to count the final duration a member stayed in the system like as for id 1 it is 12 days (7083-7071) + 2 days (7087 to 7089) + 4 days (7095 to 7099). So the total is 18 days.   (There are some duplicate entered and left values but other columns (not shown here) are not same, so these rows were not removed.) .  Since i'm working in sas so the idea can be both in sas data or the sas-sql format.

For member 2, there is no overlap of values. So the day count is 2 (8921 to 8923) + 5 days (8935 to 8940) = 7 days. I was able to solve this case as the days didn't overlap but for overlap case, any suggestion or code/advice is appreciated.

```
id  Entered  left
 1    7071   7077
 1    7071   7077
 1    7075   7079
 1    7077   7083
 1    7077   7083
 1    7078   7085
 1    7087   7089
 1    7095   7099
 2    8921   8923
 2    8935   8940
```

So the final table should be of the form

```
id  days_in_system
 1       18
 2       7
```

Comment: In your example for id 1 you are not counting two extra days from your 6th row - 7083 and 7084, which are not present in any other rows, assuming that you don't include the day that the member left. I think your total should be 20, not 18. Is that right?

Comment: Hi @user667489 , apologies for the delayed response, 7083 and 7084 are not counted as such as they will already be counted since the id 1 person was in the system from 7071 to 7085. You can look at it from this angle, since the entered date 7075 (in row 3) is less than 7077 (in row 2), so basically the person is already in system.

Comment: @user667489 : (continued from above) - Similarly for 7083 and 7084 we have a record which goes from 7078 to 7085 however an earlier record said that id 1 had entered on 7077 and left on 7083. But since 7078 was less than 7083,so again an overlap occurred and the date got extended from 7083 to 7085 (owing to the new record). I hope that helps. Please correct me if that doesn't make sense. Also I will check the idea that you shared below and will let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a surprisingly tricky problem as every row has to be compared to every other row for the same id to check for overlaps and if there are multiple overlaps you have to be very careful not to double-count them.

Here's a hash-based solution - the idea is to build up a hash containing all of the individual days a member has stayed as you go along, then count the number of items in it at the end:

```
data have;
input id  Entered  left;
cards;
 1    7071   7077
 1    7071   7077
 1    7075   7079
 1    7077   7083
 1    7077   7083
 1    7078   7085
 1    7087   7089
 1    7095   7099
 2    8921   8923
 2    8935   8940
 ;
 run;

data want;

length day 8;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
  declare hash h();
  rc = h.definekey('day');
  rc = h.definedone();
end;

do until(last.id);
  set have;
  by id;
  do day = entered to left - 1;
    rc = h.add();
  end;
end;

total_days = h.num_items;
rc = h.clear();
keep id total_days;

run;
```

This should be fairly light on memory as it only has to load the days for 1 id at a time.

The output from id 1 is 20, not 18 - here's a breakdown of the new days added row-by-row that I generated by adding a bit of debugging logic. If this is wrong, please indicate where:

```
_N_=1
7071 7072 7073 7074 7075 7076
_N_=2
No new days
_N_=3
7077 7078
_N_=4
7079 7080 7081 7082
_N_=5
No new days
_N_=6
7083 7084
_N_=7
7087 7088
_N_=8
7095 7096 7097 7098
_N_=1
8921 8922
_N_=2
8935 8936 8937 8938 8939
```

If you want to add only days for rows matching a particular condition, you can  pick those using a where clause on the set statement, e.g.

```
  set have(where = (var1 in ('value1', 'value2', ...)));
```

Comment: This thing worked like a charm. However, i have another question, which follows up on this. Suppose we have another column with values having categorical variables like let's say loan, credit card, debit card, demat etc...and other products. I want to count the days only when the variable in this column is credit card, demat and debit card and just ignore the dates containing the values loan. If it would have been sql, i would have used not in/in clause or simply take values from table where loan is dropped. So if you can provide an idea to augment the code, that would be great.

Comment: Also, on a side note what would be the best resource to learn about sas, i'm seeing there site but any other resource would also be appreciated. And thanks for all the help.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Requests for broad advice are generally off-topic on this site, but you might consider some of the [free SAS online courses](https://support.sas.com/edu/elearning.html?ctry=us&productType=library).

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad, it is indeed 20 days. Thanks for explaining with the help of result of the iterations.